# triangle animation issue canvas flip rotation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Hello I wanted to know if anyone can provide tips or direction on an issue i'm having with a triangle animation.  I have a partial animation that is not continuous, it jitters at the end of the animation.  I'm looking for advise how to make a full rotation.  If anyone can also assist in how to add multiple rotations that would be amazing.

Thank you ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Triangle Animation Team B</title>

</head>

<body>


<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>

<script>

function makeTriangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var Array = ['red','green', 'black'];
    var color = Array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();

}
}

makeTriangle('400','38','465','76','200','400');


var x = 200;

window.setInterval( function() {
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 500, 0);

x++;
if (x > 500) x = 300;

makeTriangle('400','38',x,'76','400','200');    
}, 20);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "jitters". Are you just trying to make the animation continuous like this: [link](http://jsbin.com/boqepa/edit?html,js,output)?

Comment: Here is a style tip regarding using a variable called `Array`: "You should also avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods" (see [JavaScript Reserved Words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp))

Comment: Jeremy thank you, I appreciate your assistance and tip on the array.  The animation looks much cleaner and flows nicely.

Comment: Would you have andy advise on how to make the animation flip a one or two more times across the screen?

Comment: You have code that moves one point of a triangle moving, so you could do the same thing on the remaining two stationary triangle points. There are also JavaScript libraries that make animations easier. Are you limited to canvas? If not you could try snap from Adobe with SVG (free).